# R and data.table: How to join two tables with selected columns from the second table

Tags: r, data.table, left-join

I'm able to join two tables with selected columns from the second but first I do not understand it and second I assume there is another solution.

Here are the two tables:

```
small <- data.table(a=rep(1:3, each=2)
                  , b=rep(letters[1:3], 2)
                  , c=round(runif(6)*10)
                  , d=1:6
                  , e=LETTERS[1:6]
                   ) 
big   <- data.frame(a=rep(1:3, each=4)
                  , b=rep(letters[1:3], 4)
                    )
```

I want to left join table `big` with table `small`:

```
(res <- small[big,c(names(big),"c","d"), on = c("a","b"), with=FALSE])
```

This gives me the correct result. But I would like to know if there is a more SQL-similar solution with * like (`SELECT big.*, small.c, small.d`) and also avoiding `with`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try `.SDcols` and use `.SD` to achieve your desired columns

```
small[
    big,
    .SD,
    on = .(a, b),
    .SDcols = c(names(big), "c", "d")
]
```

or

```
small[
    big,
    .SD,
    on = .(a, b),
    .SDcols = a:d
]
```

which gives

```
    a b  c  d
 1: 1 a 10  1
 2: 1 b  6  2
 3: 1 c NA NA
 4: 1 a 10  1
 5: 2 b NA NA
 6: 2 c  7  3
 7: 2 a  2  4
 8: 2 b NA NA
 9: 3 c  4  6
10: 3 a NA NA
11: 3 b  1  5
12: 3 c  4  6
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves one of the two issues. This code avoids `with` but still the code use `names(big)` instead of a generic abbreviation or symbol like `.` or an analalog symbol as `*` as in SQL.

Comment: @giordano I am not sure if my update fits your goal. you can take a look

Comment: Thanks. This works only if the variables have an order. Imagine there is no order and table `big` has 20 columns and I want all of them and table `small` has 20 variables but I want only 2 of them. Probably the only solution is using `names(big)`. I thought there is more a `data.table`-like solution with a special syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the below `dplyr::left_join()`

```r
library(dplyr)

small_big <- big %>% left_join(small, by=c('a','b'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
   a b  c  d    e
1  1 a  7  1    A
2  1 b  5  2    B
3  1 c NA NA <NA>
4  1 a  7  1    A
5  2 b NA NA <NA>
6  2 c  5  3    C
7  2 a  0  4    D
8  2 b NA NA <NA>
9  3 c  7  6    F
10 3 a NA NA <NA>
11 3 b  3  5    E
12 3 c  7  6    F
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution with `data.table`. In case of `dplyr` the solution would be `small_big <- big %>% left_join(small[,c("a","b","c","d"), by=c('a','b'))`.